# calculate fat free mass and apply the function to data set

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 ID SEX WEIGHT  BMI
 1  2   65      25
 1  2   65      25
 1  2   65      25
 2  1   70      30
 2  1   70      30
 2  1   70      30
 2  1   70      30
 3  2   50      18
 3  2   50      18
 4  1   85      20
 4  1   85      20
```

I want to calculate fat free mass (FFM) and attach the value in a new column in the dataset for each individual. These are the functions to calculate FFM for males and females:

for males (SEX=1):

```
FFMCalMale <- function (WEIGHT, BMI) {
FFM = 9270*WEIGHT/(6680+216*BMI)
}
```

and for females (SEX=2):

```
FFMCalFemale <- function(WEIGHT, BMI) {
FFM = 9270*WEIGHT/(8780+244*BMI)
```

}

I want to modify this function so it check for the SEX (1, male or 2 is female) then do the calculation for FFM based on that and apply the function for each individual. Could you please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the answer in sql? im not too sure in what language I need to write it

Comment: @Alex I am not sure what u mean by sql. The answer would be a digit number. I want to put a new column to the dataset called (FFM) with the anser in it. The same style as the BMI column for each individual.

Comment: In what language is your code?

Comment: There is something wrong with your formula for females: >  FMCalFemale(80, 30)  ans:[1] 84.17707 . How can FFM be more than WEIGHT? (although this is not a R language issue)

Comment: @rnso You are right =) I missed something in the equation. it should be FFM=9270*WT/(8780+244*BMI). Thank you for paying attention :)

Comment: @rnso the equations are from a paper titled "Quantification of Lean Bodyweight", if you are interested.

Comment: @ Amer: Thanks for your responses. It may be good to correct the equation in your question as sometimes biology students may search and reach here and just copy you equations.

Comment: @rnso correction done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ifelse`

```
data$FFM <- ifelse(data$SEX==1, 
                   FFMCalMale(data$WEIGHT, data$BMI), 
                   FFMCalFemale(data$WEIGHT, data$BMI))
```

Answer (score 1):

A data.table approach:

```
mydata <- read.table(
  header = T, con <- textConnection
  ('
ID SEX WEIGHT  BMI
1  2   65      25
1  2   65      25
1  2   65      25
2  1   70      30
2  1   70      30
2  1   70      30
2  1   70      30
3  2   50      18
3  2   50      18
4  1   85      20
4  1   85      20
   '), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
close(con)
library(data.table) ## load data.table
setDT(mydata) ## convert the data to datatable
FFMCalMale <- function (WEIGHT, BMI) {
  FFM = 9270*WEIGHT/(6680+216*BMI)
}
FFMCalFemale <- function(WEIGHT, BMI) {
  FFM = 9270*WEIGHT/(8780+BMI) 
}
setkey(mydata, SEX)
mydata[, FFM := ifelse(SEX == 1,
                       FFMCalMale(WEIGHT, BMI),
                       FFMCalFemale(WEIGHT, BMI))][]

#    ID SEX WEIGHT BMI      FFM
# 1:  2   1     70  30 49.30851
# 2:  2   1     70  30 49.30851
# 3:  2   1     70  30 49.30851
# 4:  2   1     70  30 49.30851
# 5:  4   1     85  20 71.63182
# 6:  4   1     85  20 71.63182
# 7:  1   2     65  25 68.43271
# 8:  1   2     65  25 68.43271
# 9:  1   2     65  25 68.43271
# 10:  3   2     50  18 52.68243
# 11:  3   2     50  18 52.68243
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways, one just taking the dataframe (assuming it contains columns with the names `SEX`, `WEIGHT`, and `BMI`):

```
dffunc <- function(dataframe) {
   ifelse(dataframe$SEX == 1, 
      9270 * dataframe$WEIGHT / (6680 + 216 * dataframe$BMI), 
      9270 * dataframe$WEIGHT / (8780 + dataframe$BMI))
}
```

or as you originally formatted it, but adding the `SEX` parameter:

```
func <- function(WEIGHT, BMI, SEX) {
   ifelse(SEX == 1, 
      9270 * WEIGHT / (6680 + 216 * BMI), 
      9270 * WEIGHT / (8780 + BMI))
}
```